# What happens with my app if one day Expo is unavailable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am building an app in react native detached and I was wondering what would happen if one day Expo is no longer available or get shut down so then my app is not able to run bc it relies on expo.

Is it possible that I have my own javascript bundle locally or running on my server so I don't have to rely on expo at all. If so what changes are needed so my .apk file is not relying on expo but rather on my own bundle.js

Comment: Your production application will continue to work irrespective expo is available or not. The problem is you will not be able to modify the code or create new expo app. Though, you can eject expo, remove expo specific components and rebuild app for more changes.

Comment: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/self-hosted-remote-js-bundle--assets search the internet before asking a question they are planning for local hosted bundle files and yes @AtulSharma is right

Comment: @AtulSharma what do u exactly mean I will not be able to modify the code? I just want to make sure that I understood your answer correctly. Are you saying that when I am building for production I will have my own bundle.js (javascript code running within the production build) if I decide to add changes in future how do I make sure the changes are affected if I am not using EXPO at all. Would be great if you added this as an answer and in more detailed answer so I can accept as an Answer!

Comment: also would this work import {Constants, Location, Permissions} from 'expo'; if Expo is not available as a service?

Answer (score 0):

The eject command doesn't depend on expo, so if one day expo stops working, you can detach your project from theirs and start building your own apk.

Comment: I am already detached and I already have my own apk but the thing is the apk does not work if you dont have a javascript running somewhere for example currently bundle.js is build and hosted on Expo. how can I run this bundle.js somewhere on my own server or locally

Comment: How I understand is, your apk file needs some javascript code to run and tha javascript currently is hosted on EXPO.